# How to ignore multiple clang warnings?

Tags: c++, clang

The following code works to ignore `-Wswitch`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
<code here>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and this successfully ignores `-Wswitch-enum`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum"
<code here>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

however, combining both of them using the method from [this blog](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/01/27/clang-manually-disable-warnings-in-a-specific-location/) does not work:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum -Wswitch"
<code here>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and throws the following error:
`error : unknown warning group '-Wswitch-enum -Wswitch'`

What is the proper way to ignore multiple clang warnings?

Comment: Put each one on its own line? `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"` `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum"` `

Comment: That works! I would also like to know why what I attempted did not work for me but seems to work for other people, however this does answer the question so I will accept it if you post it as a solution.

Comment: I see other people posting multiple groups on a single line, but maybe that's for other compilers. The clang source indicates that only one group is permitted. https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Pragma_8cpp_source.html (line 1295)